# Database tables not showing in HUE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am not able to see the tables under database when user login to hue(circle keeps rotating) and also it takes a quite a long time to load but in command line its fine.and it went off all of a sudden.

Comment: Which database are you using for Hue

Comment: @BruceWayne 22 sybase IQ and and metastore is with mysql.